# Airflow Helm - how to override default postgres credentials?

Tags: airflow, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I'm using the official Airflow Helm to try out the new LocalKubernetesExecutor feature. However, I also wanted the following:

1. allow helm to bring up the postgresql container
2. change the credentials, username and database for that container.

I don't really know how to do this.
I tried overriding the file section postgresql:

```
postgresql:
  enabled: true
  postgresqlPassword: airflow
  postgresqlUsername: airflow
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything. I fetched the connection that was created and decoded the base64 string:

```
 kubectl get secret airflow-airflow-metadata -o json                                             
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "data": {
        "connection": "cG9zdGdyZXNxbDovL3Bvc3RncmVzOnBvc3RncmVzQGFpcmZsb3ctcG9zdGdyZXNxbC5haXJmbG93OjU0MzIvcG9zdGdyZXM/c3NsbW9kZT1kaXNhYmxl"
    },
    "kind": "Secret",
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "meta.helm.sh/release-name": "airflow",
            "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace": "airflow"
        },
        "creationTimestamp": "2022-11-20T20:14:30Z",
        "labels": {
            "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": "Helm",
            "chart": "airflow",
            "heritage": "Helm",
            "release": "airflow",
            "tier": "airflow"
        },
        "name": "airflow-airflow-metadata",
        "namespace": "airflow",
        "resourceVersion": "7643",
        "uid": "14fff962-aec8-4862-b598-4ae3dbeca26f"
    },
    "type": "Opaque"
}
```

When I decode the connection:

```
echo cG9zdGdyZXNxbDovL3Bvc3RncmVzOnBvc3RncmVzQGFpcmZsb3ctcG9zdGdyZXNxbC5haXJmbG93OjU0MzIvcG9zdGdyZXM/c3NsbW9kZT1kaXNhYmxl | base64 -D

postgresql://postgres:postgres@airflow-postgresql.airflow:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable%
```

I'm beginning to think that it is something very simple I'm missing, or it can't be done.

So, the question is - how to override postgres user, password, and database when using official Airflow Helm? Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

connections in airflow cannot be overridden. you have to delete the connection and import the updated connection json.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change this in your values.yaml?

```
metadataConnection:
user: postgres
pass: postgres
protocol: postgresql
host: ~
port: 5432
db: postgres
sslmode: disable
```